# Normalization in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

When I use the normalization with keras:

```
tf.keras.layers.Normalization()
```

**Where should I use it?**

I adapt it with train data:

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=0)

normalization_layer = tf.keras.layers.Normalization()
normalization_layer.adapt(x_train)
```

And then, I can normalize the data (train and test) prior to use in model.fit and model.evaluate:

```
x_train = normalization_layer(x_train)
x_test = normalization_layer(x_test)
```

Or include the layer in de network model, as the FIRST layer

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(normalization_layer)
...
```

If I use the latter option:

- Does this normalization is applied to train (on model.fit) and test (on model.evaluate) or is only aplplied on mode.fit?
- During training (model fit) is this normalization applied ON EACH batch/epoch or the algorithm is smart enough to only apply the normalization once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `adapt` method computes mean and variance of provided data (in this case train data). When this layer is added to model it uses those values to normalize the input data. This is simply done by

```
output = (input - mean)/sqrt(var)
```

where `mean` and `var` are values computed in the `adapt` method.

You should only use train data for the adapt step as test data should not be used anywhere in creating/training the model.

Comment: I only train with train data ('x_train', 'y_train') data (model.fit). My question is: if I set the normalization layer inside the model (the first layer). Does normalization is applied during 'fit' (using training data) or is applied too during 'evaluate' (with the test data)?

Comment: It is applied every time the model is used, so both in training and evaluation. It is just like regular layer. It uses the same parameters (computed using train data) for training and evaluation.

Comment: @maciek97k, thanks! Do you know if, during fitting, the normalization is applied in each batch/epoch, or the algorithm is smart enough to avoid this calculation (only performs  the normalization the first time?)

Comment: It is applied every batch, but comparing to other layers this operation is rather fast. If you want to avoid it, you can compute these values before training and apply them to you data.